# Setting up and saving connection profile in SQL Workbench/j from command line/batch

Tags: sql, batch-file, sql-workbench-j

Using the guide https://www.sql-workbench.eu/manual/commandline.html#commandline-connect-noprofile

 to set up as profile and save the profile for future use.

 This is possible manually via "7.2. Managing profile groups"
https://www.sql-workbench.eu/manual/profiles.html#profile-workbench-settings

Is it possible to save a profile via the command line?

```
SQLWorkbench64.exe -username=user -password=pass -url=jdbc.. -driver=Redshift driverJar=filepath
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct support for this.

But you can use the [WbStoreProfile](https://www.sql-workbench.eu/manual/console-mode.html#console-saveprofile) command to store the currently active connection as a profile.

You can do this through the [`-command`](https://www.sql-workbench.eu/manual/using-scripting.html#scripting-command) parameter.

```
SQLWorkbench64.exe  -command="WbStoreProfile -name=test" -username=user -password=pass -url=jdbc.. -driver=Redshift driverJar=filepath
```

That will connect to the database, then run the `WbStoreProfile` command and exit again.

The profile will be saved under the name "test" in `wb-profiles.properties`.

But it's probably easier to edit `wb-profiles.properties` manually.

Comment: Unfortunately, this hasn't worked. Are you sure the double quotes are needed for "WbStoreProfile -name=test"?  @SQL WorkbenchJ

Comment: @IOIOIOIOIOIOI: sorry, there was a `=` missing. You  need some kind of quoting. If you run this from a batch file, single quotes might work better. This is always tricky with Windows.

Comment: SQL WorkbenchJ, I'm able to connect to the profile on SQL Workbench via the code below but the script won't run. Any help on syntax will be greatly appreciated.
"file_path\SQLWorkbench64.exe" -profile=pro -script='file_path\code.sql'

Comment: This is now resolved - double quotes work for Windows.>>>> wbconnect -profile=prof -script="file_path"